# Imagem transparente e cor de fundo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"\path\imagem1.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Image image = Image.FromStream(fs);
fs.Close();

Bitmap b = new Bitmap(image);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b);

graphics.DrawString("Meu texto", new Font("Arial", 50), Brushes.White, 0, 0);
b.Save(@"\path\resultado.png", image.RawFormat);

image.Dispose();
b.Dispose();
```

Imagem1:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Sim, tem imagem aí!** Mas ela além de não ter cor de fundo, também tem um grande nível de transparência.

O problema é que eu gostaria de colocar um background nela, assim o resultado seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei desenhar um retângulo vermelho, mas ele sobrepõe a imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, o código a seguir resolveu o problema:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"\path\imagem1.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Image image = Image.FromStream(fs);
fs.Close();

var imageHeight = image.Height;
var imageWidth = image.Width;

Bitmap b = new Bitmap(image);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b);
graphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(255, Color.Red));

graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

graphics.DrawString("Meu texto", new Font("Arial", 50), Brushes.White, 0, 0);
b.Save(@"\path\resultado.png", image.RawFormat);

image.Dispose();
b.Dispose();
```